# Closed formula for LDU decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I know how LDU decomposition works and moreover, I know that these closed formulas are more difficult to compute and hence it is not done in practice, but I want to understand the following cite from Wikipedia:

> Closed formula
> When an LDU factorization exists and is unique, there is a closed (explicit) formula for the elements of L, D, and U in terms of ratios of determinants of certain submatrices of the original matrix A.In particular, $D_{1}=A_{1,1}$ and for i = 2 , … , n $D_i$ is the ratio of the i -th principal submatrix to the ( i − 1 )-th principal submatrix. Computation of the determinants is computationally expensive, so this explicit formula is not used in practice.

Unfortunately I do not understand how this formula looks. Especially what is the i-th principal submatrix. I am not familiar with this term and it is not explained in more detail. I tried reformulating the recursive formulas that are usually used to explicit ones but this gets very fast very messy and I did not find an easy technique for doing so.

Here is the full wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

EDIT: Hello,

I was thinking about it since yesterday and as soon as I post the question, I realize what part of the answer must be. The definition of principal submatrix that is meant, it also called leading principal submatrix and obtained by keeping the first i rows and column of a matrix and eliminating the others. Hence $D_i = \frac{det A_i}{det A_{i-1}}$. The part that is still missing is the formula for $L_i$ and $U_i$.

Comment: Yes, exactly. The closed formulas use determinants and are therefore expensive to compute. Not LDu decomposition itself.

Comment: Ok, misunderstood!

Comment: There has been some drift in the jargon since Householder (1975), which reference you have omitted from your Wikipedia quote.  You may find more information under a more recent synonym: "leading principal minor".  Also, there are direct formulae relating an LU and an LDU -- see https://vismor.com/documents/network_analysis/matrix_algorithms/S7.SS2.php, for instance.

Comment: Hello, thank you for you answer. Yes you are right, I missed this cite. I already tried to get access to a free copy of the book, but unfortunately so far I have not found one (my university does not have access to it). I also looked at the link you posted, but I think the formulas there apply only if the matrix L, D, U are already given - or am I missunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2):

Use slice notation $m:n=[m,m+1,..,n]$, so that for example $A_i=A_{1:i,1:i}$. Then we want to achieve the decomposition in the step $i\to i+1$
$$
A_{i+1}=\pmatrix{A_i&A_{1:i,i+1}\\A_{i+1,1:i}&A_{i+1,i+1}}
=
\pmatrix{L_i&0\\L_{i+1,1:i}&1}
\pmatrix{D_i&0\\0&d_{i+1}}
\pmatrix{U_i&U_{1:i,i+1}\\0&1}
$$
Of course, $A_i=L_iD_iU_i$ by iteration assumption. Also from the determinant laws, $\det(A_i)=\det(D_i)$ so that $d_{i+1}=\det(A_{i+1})/\det(A_i)$.

For the other parts multiply out the matrix product
$$
=\pmatrix{L_iD_i&0\\ L_{i+1,1:i}D_i&d_{i+1}}
\pmatrix{U_i&U_{1:i,i+1}\\0&1}
=
\pmatrix{A_i&L_iD_iU_{1:i,i+1}\\L_{i+1,1:i}D_iU_i&L_{i+1,1:i}D_iU_{1:i,i+1}+d_{i+1}}
$$
to then get
$$
L_iD_iU_{1:i,i+1}=A_{:i,i+1}=(L_iD_iU_i)A_i^{-1}A_{1:i,i+1}\implies U_{1:i,i+1}=U_iA_i^{-1}A_{1:i,i+1}
\\
L_{i+1,1:i}D_iU_i=A_{i+1,1:i}=A_{i+1,1:i}A_i^{-1}(L_iD_iU_i)\implies L_{i+1,1:i}=A_{i+1,1:i}A_i^{-1}L_i
\\
d_{i+1}=A_{i+1,i+1}-L_{i+1,1:i}D_iU_{1:i,i+1}
$$
Remember that the entries of $A_i^{-1}=\frac{A_i^\#}{\det(A_i)}$ (using the adjoint/adjunct/adjugate which is the transpose of the co-factor matrix) are fractions of determinants, and for further consideration, that constructs like $A_i^\#A_{1:i,i+1}$ can be interpreted as consisting of Lagrange determinant formulas, giving $-\bigl(A_{i+1}^\#\bigr)_{1:i,i+1}$. Thus in total
$$ 
U_{1:i,i+1} = -\frac{U_i\bigl(A_{i+1}^\#\bigr)_{1:i,i+1}}{\det(A_i)}\\
L_{i+1,1:i} = -\frac{\bigl(A_{i+1}^\#\bigr)_{i+1,1:i}L_i}{\det(A_i)}
$$

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your detailed answer, which gives an recursive formulation of LDU decomposition. Ir definitely helped me understand why the formula for $d_i$ holds. For the $L_i$ and $U_i$ matrices I am still missing the closed formulas. Do you know how one can transform these?